# android data to pass to another activity using intent

Tags: android

Hello I'm new to android programming. I would like to ask how can I pass data to another activity using intent? My case here is, I have a 3 radiobuttons, if the user clicks on the 1st button and finally clicks the OK button, it should be retrieved(the text) to the other activity.

0 Option 1
0 Option 2
0 Option 3

then in the other activity it should be like this:
Option 1 is chosen.

Comment: Checkout this- http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/07/passing-data-using-intent-object.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass as data Between Two Activities:

```
calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
private OnClickListener calculateButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String strtext="";
             if(RadioButton1.isChecked())
             {
              strtext=RadioButton1.getText();
             }
             if(RadioButton2.isChecked())
             {
             strtext=RadioButton1.getText();
             }
             if(RadioButton1.isChecked())
             {
              strtext=RadioButton3.getText();
             }
             if(!strtext.equals(""))
             {
               //Create new Intent Object, and specify class
                Intent intent = new Intent();  
                intent.setClass(SenderActivity.this,Receiveractivity.class);

                //Set your data using putExtra method which take 
                //any key and value which we want to send 
                intent.putExtra("senddata",strtext);  

                //Use startActivity or startActivityForResult for Starting New Activity
                SenderActivity.this.startActivity(intent); 
             }
        }
    };
```

and in Receiveractivity :

```
//obtain  Intent Object send  from SenderActivity
  Intent intent = this.getIntent();

  /* Obtain String from Intent  */
  if(intent !=null)
  {
     String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("senddata");
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
  else
  {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I've put that in OnClick, but my app crashed.

Comment: see my edit answer or if app is still crashing then post your code

Answer (score 1):

In your First Activity use something like this:

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public onClick(View view) {
        RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
        intent.putExtra("Radio Choice", selected.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In your Second.onCreate() Activity, use this to retrieve the selected RadioButtons' text:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
    String choice = extras.getString("Radio Choice");
```